# Как на эмуляторе Android открыть локальный файл?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Как на эмуляторе Android открыть локальный файл? Пробовал через Денвер, но не получилось 
`http://localhost/index.html` в браузере все ок, а на эмуляторе не пашет.

Comment: локальный для кого?

Comment: по отношению к компу) на компе запущен Денвер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас есть веб-сервер (Apache, GlassFish, и т.п.), который запущен локально на машине разработчика, то на машине разработчика он виден по умолчанию на localhost. Но localhost машины разработчика - это совсем не localhost эмулятора (поскольку сервер запускается не на эмуляторе). Чтобы увидеть страницу сайта машины разработчика, надо обращаться по специальному ip из [Network Address Space](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses), а именно: 10.0.2.2. То есть вместо, http://localhost:8080, надо писать http://10.0.2.2:8080.

Answer (score 0):

1. скопировать на/с устройство/а, через DDMS (перспектива в эклипсе, добавляется с ADT плагином)
2. найти на эмуляторе и открыть

можно через консоль, но оставим этот секрет для следующего вопроса =)

Comment: а через Denwer или ноду не как?

Comment: обновил ответ... через консоль... Денвер? он какое отношение имеет к андроиду?)

Comment: ну мне надо посметреть как фал будет виден в браузере андроида

Comment: файл? веб страничка?

Comment: да там js html css и juery

Comment: ну так есть они у тебя на сервере уже работают, можешь с эмулятора зайти на них по айпи

Comment: у мя они на локальном сервере, на денвере. Как по ip зайти
в поисковую строку его ввести